# Subset Sum using Recursion in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Hi everybody I was having trouble on how to create a recursive function that takes in a list and a number and outputs true if the sum of any two numbers in the list is equal to the number being inputed. If there is no possible sum from a subset of any two numbers in said list, the program returns false. Here is all I have so far

def subSetSum(array,x):

Comment: Why does this need recursion?

Comment: My teacher is just asking for a recursion based solution

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any need for recursion here. This is also a well known algorithm, common in coding interview questions

```
def doesPairSumExist(array, total):
    seen = set()
    for n in array:
        if total - n in seen:
            return True
        else:
            seen.add(n)
    return False
```

`[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `total = 5` is True

`[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `total = 8` is False

`[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `total = 2` is False

Comment: My teacher is specifically asking for recursion is there any chance you could show me how it is done with recurison

Comment: @RajeshKumar you might find some help here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213929/finding-pairs-that-add-up-to-a-given-sum-using-recursion

Comment: thats in java plus it takes in more than two things im getting more confused any chance you could show me how to do it instead :(

Comment: @RajeshKumar stack overflow is not a homework service. There is no logical reason why this algorithm should be done with recursion. It makes the problem a lot more complicated for no reason.

Comment: If you would like help with a homework problem, that's fine, but you need to ask specific questions rather than "do it for me"

Comment: Ok so do you have any suggestions on how I could define a base case for this problem as I wasn't really sure how to start and I think defining the base case may give me some insight on how to do the rest of the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
def subSetSum(numarray,x):
    # base case
    if len(numarray)==0 and res != True:
        return False
    res = False
    for i in numarray:
        for e in numarray[i:]:
            if num==i+e:
               res=True
    return res
    # recursion
    subSetSum(numarray,x)
```